# ajaxSubmit Form Validation with a pop-up "processing" div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, html

I'm using ajaxSubmit on my web form. I also need to pop-up a div that shows "Processing the request" with a dimmed background upon user's click on the submit.

The code I'm using right now is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CustomerService").validationEngine({
        ajaxSubmit: true,
        ajaxSubmitFile: "processor.aspx",
        success :  function() {window.location.replace("Thankyou.aspx")},
        failure : function() {}
    })
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function DimScreen()
{
    document.getElementById("DimBlackScreen").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
```

And my HTML part for the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Send" name="Send" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="DimScreen();" />
```

Well the problem here is: whether the form passes the validation or not, the pop-up div will always show up, which is not the case I want.

Is there any way to make it detect if the form validation has passed and then display the div?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you want to display the "Processing" div *after* the validation has finished?

Comment: Well because it takes some time for the processing script (processor.aspx) to run while user is waiting for being redirected to the landing page (Thankyou.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery version 1.4 or above try this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   $("#DimBlackScreen").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
   $("#DimBlackScreen").hide();
});
```

or if you are using less version of jquery 1.4 try this

```
$().ajaxStart(function() {
   $("#DimBlackScreen").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
   $("#DimBlackScreen").hide();
});
```

Remember put all these stuff in document.ready

Comment: Where should I insert this code? Or do I replace any existing code with this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#Send").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); //prevent default submit action,, use ajax instead
      $('#DimBlackScreen').show();
      $("#CustomerService").validationEngine({
        ajaxSubmit: true,
        ajaxSubmitFile: "processor.aspx",
        success :  function() {
             $('#DimBlackScreen').hide();
             window.location.replace("Thankyou.aspx"); //or $('body').html('Thank you!');

        },
        failure : function() {}
       });// end validationEngine
 }); //end click

});//end document.ready

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Send" name="Send" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this code and it seems the preventing default submit action is not working, or should I say, the validation is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, inspired by the other two answers from alsahin and Kundan, I figured it out myself:

The only thing needs to be changed is how ajax handles the failure of validation. So I changed

```
failure : function() {}
```

to

```
failure : function() {document.getElementById("DimBlackScreen").style.visibility = "hidden";}
```

So that the pop-up "processing" div actually shows every time user clicks on the Submit button, but resets to hidden if the form doesn't pass validation.

I'm happy with my current code, but if you have any better ideas, please let me know.